# Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Metadata with date truncates at colon

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to push a bunch of PDFs that are in a SQL database into Azure blobs along with some metadata about them.  Everything is working, but when there is a colon (:) in the metadata, the data truncates.  I can manually add a : using the portal, so it doesn't appear that it is an invalid character.

Do I need to escape the : somehow when uploading via PowerShell?  I can't find anything about that.

Here is my code (PowerShell).

```
foreach ($r in $dataset.Tables[0]) {

    $pdfProperties = @{"ContentType" = "application/pdf"}

    $metadata = @{
        "invoiceid"      =$r.InvoiceId
        "shareid"        =$r.ShareId
        "generateddate"  =$r.OccurredOn # <--- TRUNCATES AT :
        "generatedby"    =$r.Actor
        "test"           ="10/1/2018 10:14:04 PM" # <--- TRUNCATES AT :
    }

    $guid = New-Guid

    if ($r.InvoiceReceipt.Length -gt 0) {
        $pdfFile = "C:\Temp\blobs\$guid.pdf"
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($pdfFile, $r.InvoiceReceipt)
        $pdfBlobName = "$guid.pdf"
        Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $ctx -Container "invoice" -File $pdfFile -Blob $pdfBlobName -BlobType Block `
            -Properties $pdfProperties -Metadata $metadata
    }   
}
```

Here is the result in the Azure portal.

[image]

Any input is appreciated.
Thad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it tuns out, **the ostensible truncation of data was merely a *display artifact*** in the Azure portal.

The data itself was correctly assigned as `[datetime]` instances, as Thad himself was able to verify with:

```
(Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blob -Container $container -Context $ctx).ICloudBlob.Metadata
```